# ExoPlayer как узнать что плеер сейчас играет что-нибудь программно?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Раньше для воспроизведения использовал стандартный MediaPlayer, у которого был метод isPlaying() - сообщал играет ли плеер в данный момент или нет.
Перешел на ExoPlayer, но теперь не знаю как мне узнать играет плеер в данный момент.

Comment: `getPlayWhenReady?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int getPlaybackState()
```

> Returns the current state of the player.

Comment: mediaPlayer1.getPlaybackState() != Player.STATE_IDLE
Помогло это